# Python modulefinder does not work on a file in another directory, unless run in an REPL environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, unix, directory

I have a directory structured like so:

```
main/
    find.py
    project/
        hello.py
        module_a.py
```

`hello.py` has the following:

```
import module_a
print('hello')
```

What I'm trying to do is use the standard library `ModuleFinder` to detect the `module_a` import. I'm able to do this in the interpreter (starting in `main`):

```
$ python3
Python 3.7.1 (default, Nov 17 2018, 18:28:26)
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> from modulefinder import ModuleFinder
>>> os.chdir('project')
>>> f = ModuleFinder()
>>> f.load_file('hello.py')
>>> print(f.modules)
{'hello': Module('hello', 'hello.py'), 'module_a': Module('module_a', 'module_a/__init__.py', ['module_a'])}
```

My `find.py` does exactly the same thing:

```
import os
from modulefinder import ModuleFinder

os.chdir('project')
f = ModuleFinder()
f.load_file('hello.py')
print(f.modules)
```

However, when I run it using `python3 find.py` from the `main` directory, it does not detect `module_a`:

```
$ python3 find.py
{'hello': Module('hello', 'hello.py')}
```

I'm able to get the `find.py` script to detect the module when I place it in the same
directory as `hello.py`, but this isn't useful to me. I'd expect that the
`os.chdir('project')` would cause the script to behave the same as if I had
placed it in the same directory, but there must be some other difference I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to load the module's imports by passing the optional `path` argument to the `ModuleFinder` constructor.

```
import sys
import os
from modulefinder import ModuleFinder

script = 'project/hello.py'
path = sys.path[:]
path[0] = os.path.dirname(script)
f = ModuleFinder(path)
f.load_file(script)
print(f.modules)
```

Outputs:

```
{'hello': Module('hello', 'project/hello.py'), 'module_a': Module('module_a', 'project/module_a/__init__.py', ['project/module_a'])}
```